# Safe bidirectional array index navigation

Tags: code-golf, array

## Introduction

Arrays are usually used with for-loops or iterators. One different task might be the use as a cheap way to rotate through a set of items, so after reaching the last index, the next item would be the first item of the array. This is useful for cases like menus and physical controls.

## Challenge

Given the size of an array, the initial index, and the movement (which can be positive, zero, or negative), output the resulting index in the array after cyclically moving through it.

As soon as a number which is greater than the current array index `+` the number of remaining indices, the added index would go out of bounds. The other way arround, substracting a greater negative value than the current index from itself, the index would be negative and therefore invalid. This should be compensated by the solution.
Also, when exceeding the index by not only one, but two or more array lengths, this should also be compensated (see example 2).

## Example input and output

> We assume (for the sake of simplicity) that arrays start at `0`.
>
> Array for visualization: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`

#### Example 1

**Input:**

Array size: `6`

Current Index: `1` (-> `'b'`)

Movement: `+5`

**Index Movement:**

`2` -> `3` -> `4` -> `5` -> `0`

**Output:**

Index: `0` (-> `'a'`)

#### Example 2

**Input:**

Array size: `6`

Current Index: `2` (-> `'c'`)

Movement: `-10`

**Index Movement:**

`1` -> `0` -> `5` -> `4` -> `3` -> `2` -> `1` -> `0` -> `5` -> `4`

**Output:**

Index: `4` (-> `'e'`)

## Objective

The solution with the fewest bytes wins the challenge.
Using Lists, Linked Lists etc. is not allowed, fixed arrays only.
Non-codegolfing languages are preferred.

Comment: Welcome! (1) I think the example array size is six, right? (2) Fewest bytes is a much more common measure to score by and is the default for the [tag:code-golf] tag.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions! i will update the post accordingly.

Comment: I predict a 2-byte solution in a stack-based language: Sum, Mod.

Comment: Are we meant to take an array (plus start index and rotation) and produce the element or the length of an array (plus start index and rotation) and produce the index?

Comment: The output is meant to be the index. the (-> 'element') annotation is there to clarify what element is expected for the index.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *Using Lists, Linked Lists etc. is not allowed, fixed arrays only.*? Be careful not to make [false assumptions about the properties of programming languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/43319).

Comment: Please use the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) next time you have another challenge idea. (I'm aware that new users might not have access to the sandbox right away.) Also, banning certain features of languages is not recommended on the site, because e.g. in this case, you're [unnecessarily penalizing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058/78410) languages like Haskell whose only built-in sequence type is linked list.

Comment: @Bubbler I believe out meta site has been special-cased so new users can use the sandbox right away.

Comment: @Adám I thought so too, but recently one of new users complained about not being able to use the sandbox, apparently due to not having enough rep.

Comment: I read the challenge and don't understand what the task actually is. Like, the "Challenge" sections seems to have a bunch of clarifications, but I don't know to what. Could you please add something like a line that explain what the input is and what the output should be in terms of the input?

Comment: I added a short paragraph in the "Challenge" section to clarify what (I think) the challenge is about. @Philipp, please check the edit history, and tell me if it's wrong.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Note: APL is not a golfing language.

-1 thanks to Bubbler.

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Takes (array size, current index, movement) as argument.

```apl
⊃|+/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FXc422/v@0R20THvX2AXmPetc86t1yaL3xo7aJj/qmBgc5A8kQD8/g/2kKZgqGCqZcINpI4dB6QwMA)

`+/`‌ sum the right argument

`⊃|` division remainder when divided by the first element of the argument

Comment: Porting one of Python answers, `⊃|+/` should work (taking one vector argument of three numbers).

Comment: @Bubbler Oh, right, of course.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
S%
```

A dyadic Link accepting the start index and the rotation on the left and the length on the right which yields the finish index.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9Y9f///0Y6CrqGBv/NAA)**

#### How?

```
S% - Link: [start, rotation]; length
S  - sum -> start + rotation
 % - modulo (length)
```

Comment: [As predicted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210742/safe-bidirectional-array-index-navigation/210744#comment496537_210742). Well, Jelly isn't really a stack-based language, but it basically behaves as one.

Comment: ...and it does not look all that much like a golfing language!

Comment: Right, ASCII-only. What is this heresy‽

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 3 bytes

```
|+/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/a7T1/2v@N1NIUzBUMOUC0UYK8YYGAA)

We've got APL and Jelly, so here comes J which is between APL and Jelly in the language hierarchy. Turns out the byte count is also in the middle :) And J is not a golfing language either.

<sup>Now the byte count is the exact average of Jelly (2B) and APL (4B)!</sup>

#### How it works

```
|+/  Left: array size, Right: 2-item array of initial index and offset
 +/  index + offset
|    modulo array size
```

Comment: Nice use of a hook!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 19 bytes

```python
lambda l,p:sum(p)%l
```

An unnamed function accepting `length, (start index, rotation)` which returns the finish index.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSFHp8CquDRXo0BTNed/QVFmXolGmoaZjoaRjq6hgaam5n8A)**

---

20s:

```python
lambda l,i,r:(i+r)%l
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSFHJ1OnyEojU7tIUzXnf0FRZl6JRpqGmY6Rjq6hgabmfwA)

```python
lambda l,*i:sum(i)%l
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSFHRyvTqrg0VyNTUzXnf0FRZl6JRpqGmY6Rjq6hgabmfwA)

```python
lambda*a:sum(a)%a[0]
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSvRqrg0VyNRUzUx2iD2f0FRZl6JRpqGmY6Rjq6hgabmfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```c
r;f(z,i,m){r=(m%z+z+i)%z;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/IOk2jSidTJ1ezushWI1e1SrtKO1NTtcq69n9mXolCbmJmnoKGZjWXQkERkJ@moRScWZVqpZqioJOZUgGmc/PLIAJFqcWlOSVAZkyeko6ZjqGOqU6aBpjW1LQmwwAjHV1DA7ARYBbIkNr/AA)

Saved 1 thanks to @att !

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/IOk2jSidTJ1ezushWI1e1SrtKO1NTtcq69n9mXolCbmJmnoKGZjWXQkERkJ@moRScWZVqpZqioJOZUgGmc/PLIAJFqcWlOSVAZkyeko6ZjqGOqU6aBpjW1LQmwwAjHV1DA7ARYBbIkNr/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Nx uU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=TnggdVU&input=NgoyCi0xMA)

```
Nx      - sum inputs
   uU   - modulo first input
```